# Magento - Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId) Returning Empty

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to return the details of an order by using `Mage::getModel('sales/order')`

The function I am calling is

```
protected function _getSalesOrder($orderId) {
return Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
}
```

I get my order ID as such (which I verified returns a valid orderID):

`$orderId = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getLastOrderId();`

I then call:

`$order = $this->_getSalesOrder($orderId);`

When I echo $order it's not returning anything and I can't quite figure out why. Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the code I give below ? You probably forget getAllItems() method.

```
protected function _getSalesOrder($orderId) {
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
   $items = $order->getAllItems();

    foreach ($items->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($item->getData());
    }
}
```